# How do I add a char filter to a Microsoft language analyzer in Azure Search?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

we want to use the language specific analyzers provided by azure search, but add the html_char filter from Lucene. Our idea was to build a custom analyzer that uses the same components (tokenizer, filters) as for example the en.microsoft analyzer but add the additional char filter.

Sadly we can't find any documentation on what exactly constitutes the en.microsoft analyzer or any other Microsoft analyzer. We do not know which tokenizers or filters to use to get the same result with a custom analyzer.

Can anyone point us in to the right documentation?

The documentation says that the en.microsoft analyzer [performs lemmatization instead of stemming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-add-language-analyzers) but I can't find any tokenizer or filter that claims to use lemmatization only stemmers.

Comment: Whoever has been voting to close: This is a relevant and well-formed question about how to programmatically interact with Azure Search. Please don’t close it. @samy I don’t know the answer offhand, but I’ll find someone who does.

Comment: Thanks @Bruce! I hope they are customizable.

Comment: I came here looking for exactly this. Good question and a valid use case. Using the built-in language-specific analyzers from Microsoft solves many things. But there are scenarios where you want to modify it slightly by removing troublesome characters, filter out HTML, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a customized version of a Microsoft analyzer, start with the Microsoft tokenizer for a given language (we have a stemming and non-stemming version), and add token filters from the set of available token filters to customize the output token stream. Note that the stemming tokenizer also does lemmatization, depending on the language.

In most cases, a Microsoft language analyzer is a Microsoft tokenizer plus a stopwords token filter and a lowercase token filter, but this varies depending on the language. In some cases we do language specific character normalization.

We recommend using the above as a starting point. The Analyze API can then be used for testing your configuration to see if it gives you the results you want.

Comment: Thanks, good to know that we can rebuild and customize the analyzer with the provided Microsoft tokenizer. We have a use-case with 24 different languages, any chance that the exact configuration for the languages where you are doing language specific character nomalization gets published somewhere? Something similar to this elasticsearch documentation would be great: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#french-analyzer

Comment: While we'd like to document these configurations, doing so is not high on our list of priorities right now. The reality of how these analyzers is configured is a lot more subtle and complex than it seems on the surface, and we need to figure out a way to explain it that doesn't drown readers in excessive implementation details.

Comment: Thank you Bruce, we will find some configurations that works for us. Would have been a god starting point though. The lemmatization part was just important. We believe and hope that the microsoft analyzers will perform better than the open source alternatives in our evaluation.